# I get tons of errors when I clone a repo from github (error CS0246)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, github

I have a problem. Every time that I clone a repo from GitHub I get all these errors. It's like VS doesn't recognize the system; and that is the cause of the problem, I think.
[Image with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HvPz.png).
I don't have this problem when I download the repo as a .zip file.

Comment: The problem could be your [nuget package sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources) are not configured correctly so Visual Studio can't install any of the BCL assemblies, but I can't explain why the behaviour would be different when compiling from a zip file.

Comment: Update: I don't think this would be an explanation now that I see the project is compiled against .NET Framework rather than .net core or .net 5/6, but it's worth checking anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Does your system contain the SDK that matches the project.
For example, if it is a .NET 4.8 project, is this installed on your system?

You can inspect the project properties (.csproj file) for any hints:

- `Project Sdk`
- `TargetFramework`

Missing SDK's can be installed via https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks

Comment: My SDK and .NET are the same. Is it possible that the problem is with the repository of the other person?

Comment: Is it a public repo? Can you share the link?

Comment: Yes, https://github.com/bartraman/oef18-2menucookies is the link.

Comment: Did you build the project? It works fine on my machine.